# how to know all peers who have joined channel

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

From hyperledger fabric, `peer channel join -b helloch.block` command which peer join channel does not generate block which will send to all peers.

So, when other organization peer have joined the channel, we do not know.

I consider it should generate a block to notify any other peer. Is there other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way of listing all peers which joined the channel in current version of Hyperledger Fabric, however there is a work in progress [FAB-5451](https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-5451?jql=text%20~%20%22service%20discovery%22) to implement service discovery so peer will be able to expose these type of information to the clients.